# How come this function isn't returning anything in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to be able to access information on the active sheet, but I can't even seem to "connect" with the sheet to begin with. I'm just wondering why this small function isn't returning anything.

I've played around with different ways to call the sheet (e.g. `getActive()`, `getActiveSheet()`, `getSheetByName()`, etc.), and changing the name of the sheet itself.

```
function CLICK (){
  var sheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  return sheetName;
}
```

I just want it to return the sheet name so I know it's accessing the sheet properly.

Answer (score 1):

For your `var` please try:

```
sheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName();
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi there are some different options you can choose depending on what you want to do. I would suggest to read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets. Here are the examples I have for you.

```
function myFunction() {

  /* To work on the first sheet sheet of the Spreadsheet, use getName(); to get the name of the spreadsheet*/
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
  /* To get the name of the active sheet*/
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName();
  /* To add values on the active cell (current selected cell)*/
  var sheet3 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().setValue(sheet2);
  /*To work on the sheet with a specific Name*/
  var sheet4 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  console.log(sheet2);
  console.log(sheet4);  

  /*The difference between getSheets()[0] and getSheetByName("name") is that getSheets()[0] 
  will always work with the first sheet even if you change position and getSheetByName() will 
  always work with the sheet you named even if you change position, the position is 0 based*/ 
}
```

Here is another function to get name, url and id of the srpeadsheet.

```
function getDetails(){

var getName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName();
var getUrl = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getUrl();
var getId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();

  console.log(getName);
  console.log(getUrl);
  console.log(getId);
}
```

Remember that if you are using a script editor that is attached to the Spreadsheet for sure you will be working on that spreadsheet. Now if you created a new script directly from script.google.com then you will need to first open the spreadsheet by using an Id or a url to open that specific spreadsheet.

I hope this helps.

Comment: its help for me, you describe whole content step by step and it resolved my same query. Thanks, buddy

Comment: Thank you so much for your response!